# Recalculate a variable on change event without duplicate code

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm making a small app that handles pricing and quotes for cloud services.

On one of my forms, I work out some pricing info in the 'me.shown' bit.
The prices for various items are read in from a mysql database on app launch, so i've already got all that info.

My price working out code is as follows:

```
    calc_vmCPUprice = vmcpuprice * cpuslider.Value
    calc_vmHDDprice = vmhddprice * hddslider.Value
    calc_vmRAMprice = vmRAMprice * memoryslider.Value

    If requirebackup.Checked = True Then
        calc_backupsetupfee = vmbackupsetupfeecost
        calc_backupfee = vmbackupcostperGB * sliderbackup.Value
    End If

    If supportcheck.Checked = True Then
        calc_supportfee = vmsupportfee
    End If
    vmmonthlycost = calc_vmCPUprice + calc_vmHDDprice + calc_vmRAMprice + calc_backupfee +         calc_backupsetupfee + calc_supportfee
    vm_monthlycost.Text = "£" & vmmonthlycost
```

I need to make my program re-calculate the 'vmmonthlycost' variable each time an item is changed.
So for example if you change the slider for cpu (cpuslider.value) then the price will obviously change as the 'calc_vmCPUprice' variable will now be different.

I dont want to copy and paste the calculation code into the change event of each item, as this will be messy and any future changes will need to be mirrored across all items etc.

What would you guys recommend as the best way of achieving this recalculation of price?

I would ideally like to take that bit of code and seperate it then call it from each change event, but as I tinker with vb as a hobbyist more than anything else, my knowledge is still limited.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sub and http://www.dotnetperls.com/function

Comment: put the code in a function and *call* it from the various change events; or do it OOP and use a Class which recalcs when a cost dependant property changes

Comment: why not put it in a function?

Comment: Thanks guys! A function was indeed the way to go, returning the cost each time it is called etc.